# Visual Web Developer Publish doesn't publish all required files

Tags: publish, visual-web-developer

With an MVC C# app that builds error-free, the Publish action (Release configuration) won't copy any of the controllers and several of files when "Publish only files required to run..." is selected.

Yes, MVC 1.0 is installed on top of ASP.net 3.5 SP1, and the MVC templates are visible in VWD.  I'm at a loss as this is so simple.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the properties of each file and make certain it states to copy when newer or copy always.

It may be set to "Don't copy"

Comment: I got used to just telling it to copy the files always, since, if I added them I want them used, and I don't mind paying a small price for publishing, to ensure everything is there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done an MVC application myself, but I do know that when you publish a plain jane asp.net application all of the files are compiled down to an assembly and placed in the bin folder of your application.

You might want to check the folder you're publishing to and see if you have that bin folder and see if you have a .dll inside of there. If not, this could possibly be your problem.

Good luck and hope this helps you.